# Bar code Printing in crystal report

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, report, code128

i  used code 128 to a generate bar code in crystal report , so when i print report in a A4 it detect well but when it print in sticker those are not detect by bar code detector but i checked using bar code  printing software it works fine,help...

Comment: is the size the same when you print it in an A4 than in sticker?

Comment: Is the printer you use for sticker different from A4 report? What make and model is the sticker printer?

Comment: Printer type is ttp 244 plus

Comment: People use software. Call labelworks v 1.12 in c#